# Does somebody know what the three characters in the image below mean?

Tags: characters

[!detail of inscription on blade of Chinese sword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfbJ8.png)

Comment: "越王劍" - The sword of the king of Yue.

Answer (score 0):

越王劍 (King of Yue Sword)

The most famous  King of Yue in history is [Goujian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goujian) (勾践), not sure if this sword belonged to him.

The famous 越王勾踐劍 looks like this

[image]